# How to generate the view files inside the bundle in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm creating a new Symfony2 project and I want to have the view files stored inside [Bundle]/Ressources/views. 
If I run the doctrine:generate:crud on an entity, it goes and generates the files in app/Resources. Which is cool for a small project but not for a big one. I need to find what steps I need to take to calibrate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base path of the generated templates is hard-coded.

Before symfony3, the line that define the path of the views was :

```
$dir = sprintf('%s/Resources/views/%s', $this->bundle->getPath(), str_replace('\\', '/', $this->entity));
```

And since symfony3 it is :

```
$dir = sprintf('%s/Resources/views/%s', $this->rootDir, str_replace('\\', '/', strtolower($this->entity)));
```

As you can see, before the bundle path was used. Now, it's the `kernel.root_dir`.

Also, the only alternative you have to override the default behavior is to override the Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Generator\DoctrineCrudGenerator and change the default path depending on the entity of the generated CRUD.

Look at the [old versions](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle/blob/2.5/Generator/DoctrineCrudGenerator.php) of the command, maybe they can help you.

Comment: I am curious why did they change it?

Comment: I also don't like the new path of CRUD files ! Why symfony is using bundles if the crud generator create files outside of bundle folder ??!!